# Filter table rows based on multiple check boxes

Tags: jquery, jquery-filter

I'm a jQuery newbie.

I have this table that needs to be filtered based on check boxes that contain values in different categories. Here is the codes that I've been working on

```
<input class="prod_status" type="checkbox" value="Discontinued">Discontinued<br/>
<input class="prod_status" type="checkbox" value="Shipping">Shipping<br/>
<input class="prod_capacity" type="checkbox" value="1GB">1GB<br/>
<input class="prod_capacity" type="checkbox" value="2GB">2GB<br/>
<input class="prod_capacity" type="checkbox" value="4GB">4GB<br/>
<input class="prod_speed" type="checkbox" value="1000MHz">1000MHz<br/>
<input class="prod_speed" type="checkbox" value="1333MHz">1333MHz<br/>
<br /><br />

<table class="someclass" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="bla">
<caption>bla bla</caption>
<thead>
    <tr id="ProductID">
    <th>Product Number</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Capacity</th>
    <th>Speed</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="Memory1" class="part_detail">
    <td class="name">Memory1</td>
    <td class="status">Shipping</td>
    <td class="capacity">1GB</td>
    <td class="speed">1333MHz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Memory2" class="part_detail">
    <td class="name">Memory2</td>
    <td class="status">Discontinued</td>
    <td class="capacity">2GB</td>
    <td class="speed">1000MHz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Memory3" class="part_detail">
    <td class="name">Memory3</td>
    <td class="status">Shipping</td>
    <td class="capacity">2GB</td>
    <td class="speed">1333MHz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Memory4" class="part_detail">
    <td class="name">Memory4</td>
    <td class="status">Discontinued</td>
    <td class="capacity">4GB</td>
    <td class="speed">1000MHz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Memory5" class="part_detail">
    <td class="name">Memory5</td>
    <td class="status">Shipping</td>
    <td class="capacity">4GB</td>
    <td class="speed">1333MHz</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

var oData = $("tbody tr.part_detail");
$(":checkbox.prod_status").change(function() {
    var checkedValues = $(":checkbox.prod_status:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();

    if (checkedValues.length > 0) {
        oData.hide();
        for (var i = 0; i < checkedValues.length; i++) {
            oData.filter(function() {
                if (checkedValues[i].toString() == $(this).find('.status').text()) 
                    $(this).show();
            });
        }
    }
    else
        $("tbody tr.part_detail").show();
});
```

I've only manage to get it to work with Status category. I basically stuck after that. I have a feeling I have made things more complicated than they should be, but my jQuery experience is not enough to make it better.

I try to summarize the requirement as follow:

- If no check box is checked, all rows will be displayed
- If one or more check boxes in a category are checked, all records that match selected values in that category are shown.
- If 1 or more check boxes in other categories are checked, only records that match all categories are shown.

In other words, logical AND is applied between different categories while logical OR is applied within a category.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not make things easier by using radio-buttons for each category; so you can only select 1 status, 1 category and 1 speed?

Comment: I added the html portion here in case you don't want to go to jsfiddle. The users are allowed to selected multiple check boxes. For example, they want to search for all 2GB and 4GB memory modules.

Answer (score 3):

see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/abhiklpm/ZEDR9/5/

I have modified your html by adding **"rel"** attributes and some **"class"** for easily accessing data:

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function () {
    var showAll = true;
    $('tr').not('.first').hide();
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        if ($(this)[0].checked) {
            showAll = false;
            var status = $(this).attr('rel');
            var value = $(this).val();            
            $('td.' + status + '[rel="' + value + '"]').parent('tr').show();
        }
    });
    if(showAll){
        $('tr').show();
    }
});
```

**Edit:**  I am having a mistake in that fiddle,

**change :**

`<td class="capacity" rel="Shipping">2GB</td>`

**to :** `<td class="capacity" rel="2GB">2GB</td>`

otherwise while 2Gb it will show only 1 result.

Comment: If I select all capacities (1GB, 2GB, 4GB), there's still one (2GB) missing.

Comment: It's almost there. If I select Shipping and 4GB, there should be only one record shown as only memory5 meets all criteria (Status = 'Shipping' AND Capacity = '4GB'). It should be like in Sql statement."Select * From part_detail Where (Status In ('Shipping','Discontinued') And (Capacity In ('1GB', '2GB', '4GB')) AND (Speed In ('1000MHz', '1333MHz'))

Comment: Good work, but the 'not first' selector should have a colon, not a period, i.e. not('.first') should be not(':first').

Comment: @RobGanly I have a class="first" for tr in html, so used not('.first')